# Jenkins job gets stuck in queue. How to make it fail automatically if the worker is offline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

So on my jenkins sometimes my worker "slave02" gets offline and needs to manually get unstuck. I will not get into details, because it's not the point of this question here.

The scenario so far:

I've configured a job intentionally to get processed on that exact worker. But obviously it would not start since the worker is offline. **I want to get notified when that job gets stuck in queue**. I've tried to use *Build Timeout Jenkins Plugin* and I've configured it to fail the build if it waits for longer than 5 minutes to complete the job.

The problem with this is that the plugin makes sure the job fails 5 minutes after the build gets started... which does not help in my case. Because the job doesn't start, rather it sits in queue waiting to get processed but that never happens. So my question is - is there a way to make the job check if that worker is down to just automatically fail the build and send notification?

I am pretty sure that can be done but I could not find a thread where this type of scenario is being discussed.

Comment: Had this problem some time ago but couldn't find a clear way to fail the build if node is not available. Instead, I let the job run on default node (master) and use `timeout(...) { node(...) {} }` with a short timeout value to test for node availability. If this passes, I run a 2nd `timeout(...) { node(...) {} }` with a much longer timeout to do the actual work.